# how to use condition if using DB::table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm trying to update or insert base on condition, but I'm getting error this condition not working.
If it notification_status DELETED it was updated table and also it create new record at same time

**code**

```
use App\Notification;


  if(DB::table('notifications')->where('user_id',$request->user_id)->where('notification_status', '=', 'ACTIVE' )){
 DB::table('notifications')->update(['user_name' => $request->user_name,]);//if notification_status ACTIVE IT GET UPDATE
    }else{
 DB::table('notifications')->insert(['user_name' => $request->user_name,]);//if notification_status DELETED CREATE NEW RECORD
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-or-insert) so you can avoid if condition

```
 DB::table('notifications')->updateOrInsert(['user_id'=>$request->user_id,'notification_status'=> 'ACTIVE'],['user_name' => $request->user_name])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply don't understand can you add your code in my code

Comment: @user12380208 i have already added code .its single line code ,

Comment: ok then no need to use if condition right

Comment: @user12380208 exactly

Comment: im getting error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user12380208 updated answer.there was typo erorr